# how can i get spinner item's id?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a spinner named spinnerArray

hot can I get the selected item's ID of spinner by integer data type after click a button?

(when I have selected First one of spinner, I want to get integer 0,Second one,integer 1)

Comment: what's wrong with `getSelectedItemId`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(final AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, final int position, final long id) {
           // position is what you want i think
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(final AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

And to get the position when clicked on other views use `spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();`

Comment: the position what i need　　　　
I have try many time to display the position(integer) but it's can't work.   　　　　But I assign the position(integer) int the array like  

　　　　　　　　　TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.uid);
　　　　　　　　　title.setText(mytitleArray[position]);

　　　　　　　　　　　　
Then i can display it....  
　　　　　　　　　　
If i do this  　　　　　title.setText(position); 　　　　　　to display the position　　　　　　　　　　
it will error....

Comment: it will throw error because you need to use `title.setText(String.valueOf(position))` or `title.setText(""+position);`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your button's onClick method:

```
mySpinner.getSelectedItemPosition() + 1;
```

`getSelectedItemPosition()` gives you the item position starting at 0, so you need to add 1.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are looking for position in spinner

> code sample

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
{
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, 
int  position, long id) {
    // your code here
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
    // your code here
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to see when the items on the spinner have been clicked? Then [OnItemSelectedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemSelectedListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener%29) will allow you to override onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id).